# Create Multiple Custom Models in Azure Form Recognizer Studio

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I have created a project in the `Form Recognizer Studio` to create `Custom Model`. I uploaded 5 sample invoices and `Labeled` them. When I complete the labeling and click on `Train`, the system created a `Custom Model`. Now I want to create more `Custom Models` under the same project so that I can create a `Compose`. But I am not able to find any documentation to help me understand how to create multiple `Custom Models` under the same project. Am I trying the right thing?

Comment: Can you add the image of your custom model?

Comment: You can assign up to 200 trained custom models to a single composed model ID , Refer here:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/compose-custom-models?view=form-recog-3.0.0&tabs=studio also, you can add all your images for Recognition in a blob storage and create custom models out of it, Refer here:-https://www.cloudthat.com/resources/blog/build-a-custom-model-using-azure-form-recognizer-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well since there isn't a lot of documentation regarding custom models. But here's a quick guide.

1. Creating a New model:
   Once the models are trained, you can delete the labels that you've had recognized previously in the "Label data" tab and upload different documents for you to train more models with. The studio will only train the model with labeled pdf's, so even if you have unlabeled pdfs in this section, that's okay. Model won't take that into account. I experimented with creating a new project within the Custom extraction tab however, it just opens up the same project page with the previous model training contents but with a new header. So, for now, we know that the models are shared across different projects as long as they share the same resource group.
2. Composing a custom model:
   Once you've trained two or more models, you can see these models in the models tab of Form Recognizer studio. It's important to note that you can only compose models of the same type. So neural models can only be composed with neural models and template models vice versa. Once you have composed these models, it doesn't mean that the model is merged and can cover everything. It means that the two models are tied to the singular model ID name, so if you call it via SDK for example, you would just need one ID, however, depending on the input document, only one of your models is going to be selected to parse the document.
3. Integration with SDK, be sure to have your API versions compatible with the relevant model call functions.

[API Compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJmTE.png)